# Django - Bug with CSRF token (CSRF verification failed. Request aborted)

Tags: django, python-3.x, debugging, csrf

I'm having a problem with the csrf token on a Django powered site, which I'm close to reporting as a bug.

Problem is basically, CSRF token fails when `DEBUG` is `False`. When `DEBUG` is `False`, if I'm using sessions for the csrf token (Django 1.11):

```
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = None
```

...all forms/post requests on the frontend fail authentication, but I can login fine to the Django admin panel, e.g., csrf token authentication succeeds.

On the other hand, if I'm using cookies for csrf, authentication on the frontend for forms/post requests go through without any problem, but then it fails for the admin login: `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Part of my `settings.py` file looks like this:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = 'DEBUG' in os.environ

# CSRF
# These are commented/uncommented depending on what method I'm testing
# CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = None

# I added the cookie domain setting after I started seeing the problem
# and hoped it would have resolved it; it didn't help.
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.{0}'.format(os.getenv('DOMAIN_NAME', 'mysite.com'))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.mysite.com',
    '.mysite.info',
]

if DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(['.mysite.dev'])

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainsite',
    'constance',
    'jstemplate',
    'compressor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'mainsite.middleware.Guid',
    'mainsite.middleware.SiteLang',
]
```

If I set `DEBUG` to `True`, I have no issues whatsoever with CSRF token authentication, both on the frontend as with logging into the Django admin panel.

I'm also using Redis as a cache. Am I missing something crucial that is causing this CSRF error? I must point out, there was a point in which I was not getting this error, but I cannot for the life of me pinpoint what change would have created this behavior with the CSRF token.

Comment: Have you made progress with your issue? I seem to have run into something similar, but I'm using python 2.7.11 / Django 1.11.1

Production scenario:

1) I can submit an AJAX form normally
2) I log into admin
3) I can no longer submit the same AJAX form

Restarting / clearing memcached resolves this issue, until I log into admin again.

Also, submitting the form in incognito will work, same goes for logging into admin from an incognito window. If I do it that way, the AJAX form will continue to work.

As far as I can tell, this issue does not occur for my users, just for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue.
I solve this by 
1. `pip install django-sslserver`. 
2. Put `sslserver` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3. `python manage.py runsslserver`